# Using findCirclesGrid() in large images

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I am using OpenCV 3 in Python 2.7 to calibrate different cameras. I use the findCirclesGrid() function, which succesfully finds a [4 by 11 circle pattern](http://robocraft.ru/files/opencv/acircles_pattern.png) in a 1 Megapixel image. However, when I try to detect the pattern up close in an image with a higher resolution, the function fails. When the object is farther away in the image, it is still detected. I use the function as follows:

```
ret, corners = cv2.findCirclesGrid(image, (4, 11), flags=cv2.CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID)
```

With larger images, it returns `False, None`. It seems that the function can't handle circles that have a too large area. I tried adding `cv2.CALIB_CB_CLUSTERING`, but this doesn't seem to make a difference. Also, it seems that in C++ the user can signify the use of blobdetector, but not in  Python. Details: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findcirclesgrid

Can I increase the maximum detection size somehow or make the function detect the pattern in another way?

Edit: I found out how to edit parameters of the blobDetector by using

```
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
params.maxArea = 100000
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
ret, corners = cv2.findCirclesGrid(self.gray, (horsq, versq), None,
                flags=cv2.CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID, blobDetector=detector)
```

Still the same issue, though.

Edit2:
Now adding `cv2.CALIB_CB_CLUSTERING` resolves the issue!

Comment: will it work if you resize the image (programmatically)? You could try a handfull of sizes and try them all. Just make sure that you rescale the detected circles afterwards to fit to the original sized image.

Comment: Perhaps, but doesn't that make a large resolution superfluous? It means I can only get the precision of the rescaled image.

Comment: then you'll probably have to look at the source code whether/why there are limitations to the detection. If you try the resizing solution you could postprocess detected circles for refinement to get higher precision (manually detected each one and use the previously detected grid connections)

Comment: Yes, I'll have a look into both options. Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing you probably need to do is tweak the min area and max area of the blob detector.
Create a  blob detector with params (don't use the default parameters), and adjust the minarea and max area that the detector will accept. You can first just show all the found blobs before you pass the detector that you have created into the findcirclesgrid function.

Python Sample code

```
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
# Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
print('params')
print(params)
print(type(params))


# Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 200
params.maxArea = 18000

params.minDistBetweenBlobs = 20


params.filterByColor = True
params.filterByConvexity = False

# tweak these as you see fit
# Filter by Circularity
# params.filterByCircularity = False
params.minCircularity = 0.2

# # # Filter by Convexity
# params.filterByConvexity = True
# params.minConvexity = 0.87

# Filter by Inertia
params.filterByInertia = True
# params.filterByInertia = False
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.01

detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(gray)

im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)



fig = plt.figure()
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(gray, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(im_with_keypoints, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB),
           interpolation='bicubic')

titlestr = '%s found %d keypoints' % (fname, len(keypoints))
plt.title(titlestr)

fig.canvas.set_window_title(titlestr)


ret, corners = cv2.findCirclesGrid(gray, (cbcol, cbrow), flags=(cv2.CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID + cv2.CALIB_CB_CLUSTERING ), blobDetector=detector )
```

Comment: Even though the question is not really relevant anymore, I'm still accepting to thank you for the trouble. Thanks, Paulus.